# How sum numbers in a list of list by name

Tags: python

I have this list of list (it is already in order by name):

```
[['Argo',2],['Argo',9],['Gim',1],['Gim',7],['Sam',10]]
```

I want this output (unique name with the relative sum):

```
[['Argo',11],['Gim',8],['Sam',10]]
```

The list of list will be update...so isn't a finite list of list. There can be more than three name and each name can have more than 2 number for example:

```
 [['Argo',2],['Argo',9],['Argo',20],['Gim',1],['Gim',7],['Sam',10],['Ted',10],['Ted',10]]
```

Comment: What did you  try?

Comment: Have you attempted to write something so we can look at it and debug, or do you simply want us to write you code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Yes, they are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

people = [["Argo",2],["Argo",9],["Gim",1],["Gim",7],["Sam",10]]

for i in people:
   d[i[0]] += i[1]

for i in d:
   the_sum = d[i]
   d[i] = the_sum/float([b[0] for b in people].count(i))

new_list = [[a, b] for a, b in d.items()]

new_val = sorted(new_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

By using defaultdict, you can updated the values associated with each individual as you loop through `people`. 
Output:

```
[['Argo', 5.5], ['Gim', 4.0], ['Sam', 10.0]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain not the sum but the average? [['Argo', 5.5], ['Gim', 4], ['Sam', 10]]

Answer (score 0):

you could create a dictionary to sum the values up und write it back to the list of lists (if you realy need it as a list)

```
name_dict = dict()

for l in your_list:
    if l[0] in name_dict:
            name_dict[1] += l[1]
        else:
            name_dict[1] = l[1]
```